# error: The argument type '(int) → dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type '(String) → void'

Tags: flutter, parameters, textfield, bloc

I have some fields which post `String` and `int`, the `String` fields are working properly and I am getting these values at the db, the at the `int` type fields I'm getting this error message.

> The argument type '(int) → dynamic' can't be assigned
>   to the parameter type '(String) → void'.

I'm using `bloc` to post to a firebase db.

here is how it looks.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final trackerBloc = Provider.of<TrackerBloc>(context);
    String docId = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Create'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: Text(
                  'Create',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                ),
              ),
              _buildNumberField(trackerBloc),
 ...
```

the `textField` itself looks like this:

```
  Widget _buildNumberField(TrackerBloc trackerBloc) {
    return StreamBuilder<Object>(
      stream: trackerBloc.numberStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return TextField(
          controller: _controllerNumber,
          onChanged: trackerBloc.numberSink, /// <- The argument type '(int) → dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type '(String) → void'.
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Equipment Number', errorText: snapshot.error),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

The bloc `Future` to create the data looks like this. here I'm already getting `null` `value` from the numberField

```
  Future<void> createData(docId) {

    final Tracker createTracker = Tracker(
        id: docId,
        comment: _commentController.value,
        exercise: _exerciseController.value,
        number: _numberController.value,
        repetition: _repetitionController.value,
        sets: _setsController.value,
        weight: _weightController.value
    );

    print(_commentController.value + _numberController.value.toString());

    return trackerDb.createData(docId, createTracker);
  }
```

The `stream` and `Sink` looks like this

```
final _numberController = BehaviorSubject<int>();

Stream<int> get numberStream => _numberController.stream.transform(validateNumbers);
Function(int) get numberSink => _numberController.sink.add;


// the vallidation process
Stream<bool> get submitValid => Observable.combineLatest6(commentStream, exerciseStream, numberStream, repStream, setsStream, weightStream, (e, m, p, q, r, t,) => true);

final validateNumbers = StreamTransformer<int, int>.fromHandlers(handleData: (numbers, sink){
  if(numbers > 1) {
    sink.add(numbers);
  } else {
    sink.addError('add at least something man');
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
 onChanged: (strNum) => trackerBloc.setsSink((int.parse(strNum))),
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to change it a bit into:   onChanged: (strNum) => trackerBloc.setsSink((int.parse(strNum))),   to work but it's still what I needed. If you can change your answer into this and I mark it as helpful.